# PHP- Inserting one value from multidimensional array into sql

Tags: php

I am trying to insert just one value from my multidimensional array into sql. It works if it is the first sub-array, like `$global['somevalue']`, but not when it is at any level below that, like `$global['somearray']['somevalue']`.

For example, this is not working:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO recent_queries (`type`, `fetched`, `expires`) VALUES ('$global[query][type]', '$global[query][fetched]', '$global[query][expires]')");
```

But this is:

```
$type = $global['query']['type'];
$fetched = $global['query']['fetched'];
$expires = $global['query']['expires'].

mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO recent_queries (`type`, `fetched`, `expires`) VALUES ('$type', '$fetched', '$expires')");
```

How can I insert to the db without having to declare new variables (working with the preexisting array)?

Comment: In your real code you use bind variables instead of building your query by concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO recent_queries (`type`, `fetched`, `expires`) VALUES ('{$global['query']['type']}', '{$global['query']['fetched']}', '{$global['query']['expires']}')");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a multidimensional array you reference them with, for example, $array['key'] and you cannot use them directly in your SQL text like a "normal" $variable, instead you need to do it like this,

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO recent_queries (`type`, `fetched`, `expires`) VALUES ('".$global['query']['type']."', '".$global['query']['fetched']."', '".$global['query']['expires']."')");
```